# Make pyright/PyCharm recognize arguments set by decorator

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators, pydantic, pyright

I have the following decorator function (simplified version of `serialize_request` from [`api-client-pydantic`](https://github.com/mom1/api-client-pydantic)) that is supposed to be used on a function that takes any number of `pydantic` models as parameters. It initializes those models with the arguments passed to it and then calls the wrapped function with these models as arguments.

```py
def serialize(extra_kwargs: Dict[str, Any] = None) -> Callable:
    extra_kw = extra_kwargs or {"by_alias": True, "exclude_none": True}

    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        map_schemas = {}
        map_params = {}
        parameters = []

        for arg_name, arg_type in get_type_hints(func).items():
            if arg_name == "return":
                continue
            map_schemas[arg_name] = arg_type
            if inspect.isclass(arg_type) and issubclass(arg_type, BaseModel):
                # the model's signature contains only aliases
                arg_fields = list(arg_type.__fields__.keys())
                arg_params = inspect.signature(arg_type).parameters
                map_params[arg_name] = set(list(arg_params.keys()) + arg_fields)
                parameters.extend(list(arg_params.values()))

        @wraps(func)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if map_schemas:
                data, origin_kwargs = {}, {}
                for arg_name, arg_type in map_schemas.items():
                    if inspect.isclass(arg_type) and issubclass(arg_type, BaseModel):
                        arg_kwargs = {
                            k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in map_params[arg_name]
                        }
                        data[arg_name] = parse_obj_as(arg_type, arg_kwargs).dict(
                            **extra_kw
                        )
                    else:
                        val = kwargs.get(arg_name)
                        if val is not None:
                            origin_kwargs[arg_name] = val
                new_kwargs = {**origin_kwargs, **data} or kwargs
                return func(*args, **new_kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        # Override signature
        if parameters:
            sig = inspect.signature(func)
            _self_param = sig.parameters.get("self")
            self_param = [_self_param] if _self_param else []
            sig = sig.replace(parameters=tuple(self_param + parameters))
            wrap.__signature__ = sig  # type: ignore

        return wrap

    return decorator
```

By overwriting the signature, tools like ipython recognize the new arguments and show them in the pop up help. For example, with the below models and function:

```py
class ModelA(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: int


class ModelB(BaseModel):
    one: float
    two: Optional[str] = None


@serialize()
def foo(model_a: ModelA, model_b: ModelB):
    print(model_a)
    print(model_b)
```

In PyCharm:
[image]

In pure ipython:
[image]

But pyright doesn't recognize them and shows an error:

[image]

I don't know what PyCharm uses internally, but it also doesn't recognize the new arguments. It doesn't show an error though, it just accepts anything as valid arguments, also none at all:

[image]

Now, my question is if there is some way to make pyright/PyCharm and similar tools recognize those "new" arguments set by the decorator and make them behave as though the parameters were set as such on the function directly.

Comment: How did you achieve pyright in-line errors in PyCharm? I don't see a plugin available that could provide this.

Comment: The screenshot with the inline error is from neovim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such way to do this with Python's current typing system.

These are the ingredients that you would need to use:

- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#decorators
- https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#parameter-specification-variables

But what you describe is far beyond their capabilities.